# Trouble connecting to my git repository from windows to linux

Tags: windows, linux, git

I have git installed on my local windows 7 PC. I can commit there. 
I have git installed on my linux dev server. I can commit there. 
I have successfully cloned to each machine a github repository. So they seem to be working in that sense. But I'd like to be able to push from my PC to the dev server.

I believe that I am missing a crucial piece of info here and can't find any tutorials, questions answered on how to set this up.

I have a few questions:

- I was led to believe that I don't NEED to set up ssh keys to do this, I will just be prompted for a password.
- My site was developed in php, is it possible to push to the linux server and have the live dev site continue running, with the new changes?

Here is how I'm currently trying to clone from my linux server and the response... (i changed the IP address)

```
C:\DevEnv>git clone 0.0.0.0:gitrepo.git
Cloning into 'gitrepo'...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have a directory called gitrepo.git that has a repository.

I also tried creating a repository in the home dir of mysite.com. When I try cloning that from my PC this is what happens:

```
C:\DevEnv>git clone http://mysite.com
Cloning into 'mysite.com'...
fatal: http://mysite.com/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I've read through many tutorials and they mostly talk about either really really basic concepts, or how to push/pull to github, or just skip over certain settings so when I follow them I get fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly...

Any help, point in the right direction would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to provide your username. For example:

```
$ git clone myusername@myhost.com:/opt/git/project.git
```

Or you could setup a samba-share on the Linux box and share your git-repo, mount the share in windows and clone it from the filesystem.

More info about setting up git on a server:
http://progit.org/book/ch4-0.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Check path to your project.
2. Try to clon via git protocol:

   `C:\DevEnv>git clone git://0.0.0.0/gitrepo.git`